# Strategy for storing many directories / files

Tags: php, apache, io, storage

I'm currently in the process of building a website that will be dealing with (potentially) millions of users. For these users, I have to store the following:

1. An avatar (JPG / PNG file)
2. A unknown number of files (realistically up to 1000).

I have several initial questions:

1. Since I envision a linux server running Apache and PHP 7, what are my limits regarding number of files / number of (nested) directories? I'm asking this with expectation that the answer will apply to the most common FS available via web hosts.
2. What performance benefits / losses will be experienced with a complex vs a simple storage pattern (e.g. many directories vs. a few).
3. Using shards seems like a good idea, but do you run into a problem with a maximum number of directories?

My current thinking (for the avatars at least) was to have a single directory for each 1000 users (using DB user ID) and storing the avatars for those users in that directory (using a 15 character hash filename). Is this a good strategy or not?

One other thing to note, is that I don't need to do a lookup of all the files in the system. I'll simply be accessing individual files using their filenames from a database.

Many thanks for your input!

Comment: You have to ask your service provider about those specifications. Only they know what filesystem they use.

Comment: That's true, however I would imagine some, if not most of my other questions are service provider agnostic.

Comment: If you store paths to files in your database, then there is no difference in performance between a flat or a deep hierarchy. You have to create more directories for a deep hierarchy, but writing performance usually is not considered crucial, since the vast majority of requests are reading.

Comment: Okay, but presumably there is limit to how many files you can store in a single directory (if nothing else, before you experience a performance drop)?

Comment: You don't experience a performance drop when a directory gets "full". But there is a hard limit. What that is depends on the type of file system and it's configuration. Which is why I suggested to contact your service provider. However it certainly is a _very_ good idea to keep things configurable in your implementation (constants), so that your code stays portable.